# Display and edit data in DataGridView

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have DataGridView with this columns:

```
____________________________________________________________
Column1  | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 |
------------------------------------------------------------
readonly |readonly |readonly |   int   |   int   |  int    |
------------------------------------------------------------
  ==     |   ==    |   ==    |   ==    |   ==    |   ==    |
------------------------------------------------------------
the last row         Total       sum   |  sum    |  sum    |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The first 3 columns are readOnly, the last 3 columns are editable (int). the last row is total of the last 3 columns and if it is modified, the sum should updat. How can I do it in C#?
All these data is retrieve from SQL server and display it in this DataGridView.

Comment: Please add some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

1/ you can set ReadOnly=True on the properties of a DataGridViewColumn.

2.1/ Using DataSets - or DataTables
If you retrieve your data from SQL using an SQLDataAdapter and fill DataTables: you can add a column with a calculated value.

2.2/ if you use an object model (or ORM) to store the data from SQL server I would suggest adding a property 'CalcualatedValue'
Make sure your class supports INotifyPropertyChanged.
Then add an event handler for event 'PropertyChanged' and update the property value of 'CalculatedValue' if needed.

Comment: Can you Kindly write it as Code?

Comment: I could add some code to make it easier, please tell me how you retrieve data from your database.

Comment: Simply, base on some Criteria run a query and I have to fill it  in this grid but i don't know how? is that what you want to know?